# My Apache server renders all HTML pages into plain text

Tags: html, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm using Apache server through `xampp`. I had HTML pages, and `localhost/*.html` used to work just fine until it stopped working and started rendering all html pages to plain text files.

I don't think I changed any configuration file, it just stopped working as weird as it sounds... what should I do, and where should I look into?

Comment: formatting and noise

Comment: @pandagrammer can you please include some example page and file name? HTML should render in a browser, even if xampp is turn off. You can open the file with any browser directly and  it should render correctly. At least there is some syntax error